# error when casting to int in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I cast a string to int, like this:

```
 <tr class="@(item.Id == (int)(Session["Id"] ?? 0) ? "sfs-selected sfs-selectable" : String.Empty)">
```

item.Id is a int

But then I get this error:

```
  Specified cast is not valid.
```

Thank you

This is my Index method:

```
[Route("sort/{SortColumn}/{SortOrder?}", Name = "Sort-Product")]
        [Route("page/{Page:int}/{SortColumn}/{SortOrder?}", Name = "Paging-Product")]
        [Route("search/{SearchString}")]
        [Route("index")]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string filter, string currentFilter, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, int? page)
        {
            IOrderedQueryable<Product> entities = (IOrderedQueryable<Product>)db.FilteredProducts;

            if (searchString != null) page = 1; else searchString = currentFilter;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;

            if (filter != null) {
                string[] filters = filter.Split(new char[] { '.' });
                filter = "";

                // filter on form
                if (filters.Length > 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filters[0])) {
                    FormLibraryEntry formEntry = FormLibraryController.GetFormLibraryEntry(filters[0], StateHelper.GetSchema());

                    if (formEntry != null) {
                        entities = (IOrderedQueryable<Product>)entities.Where(
                            s => s.FormName == formEntry.Id
                        );
                        AddFixedNotification(String.Format(Resources.Entity.Environment.FilteredByFormMessage, formEntry.Name));
                        filter += filters[0];
                    }
                }

                // filter on design template
                if (filters.Length > 1 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filters[1])) {
                    var designEntry= DesignTemplateController.GetTemplateLibraryEntry(filters[1], StateHelper.GetSchema());

                    if (designEntry != null) {
                        entities = (IOrderedQueryable<Product>)entities.Where(
                            s => s.TemplateName == designEntry.Id
                        );
                        AddFixedNotification(String.Format(Resources.Entity.Environment.FilteredByDesignTemplateMessage, designEntry.Name));
                        filter += "."+ filters[1];
                    }

                }
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
                entities = (IOrderedQueryable<Product>)entities.Where(
                        s => s.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                        || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FormName) && s.FormName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
                        || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.UrlName) && s.UrlName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
                );
                AddFixedNotification(String.Format(Resources.Entity.Environment.FilteredBySearchTermMessage, searchString));
            }

            switch (sortColumn) {
                case "id":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
                    break;
                case "name":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                    break;
                case "enabled":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.IsEnabled) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.IsEnabled);
                    break;
                case "formname":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.FormName) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.FormName);
                    break;
                case "design":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.TemplateName) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.TemplateName);
                    break;
                case "urlname":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.UrlName) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.UrlName);
                    break;
                case "forms":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.SubmittedForms.Count()) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.SubmittedForms.Count());
                    break;
                case "modified":
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.ModificationDate) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.ModificationDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    sortColumn = "name";
                    sortOrder = "";
                    entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                    break;
            }

            ViewBag.SortColumn = sortColumn;
            ViewBag.SortOrder = sortOrder == "desc" ? "desc" : "";
            ViewBag.SearchString = searchString;
            ViewBag.Filter = filter;
            Session["page"] = page;   

            int pageSize = StateHelper.GetPageSize();
            int pageNumber = StateHelper.HasPageSizeChanged ? 1 : (page ?? 1);            

            return View(entities.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

So then you see the complete Index method in combination with the view. Because This is for that you will return on the same page and selected the same row number as before

Comment: What is the value of `Session["Id"]`?

Comment: try item.Id == `Convert.ToInt32((Session["Id"] ?? 0))` hope Session["id"] is an object and it contain interger value

Comment: Thank you. but then I get this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is below :-

```
<tr class="@(item.Id == Convert.ToInt32(Session["Id"]) ? "sfs-selected sfs-selectable" : String.Empty)">
```

Because Convert.ToInt32(null) returns 0 in c#

Comment: Thank you. it works now. But it was with the "Id" propetie, Because there where more views with only "Id" So I made the Names of the Id's unique. Now it works

Answer (score 1):

I think you should cast it like this

```
int.Parse(Session["Id"].ToString())
```

**Edit**

As Neel noted Use `.TryParse()` to avoid excception in case of `Session["id"]` is `null`

```
int.TryParse(Session["Id"].ToString(), out someIntVariable)
```

Comment: thank you, like this: <tr class="@(item.Id == int.Parse((Session["Id"].ToString() ?? 0)) ? "sfs-selected sfs-selectable" : String.Empty)">

Comment: then I get this error: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' B

Comment: you do not require '??' @hallohallo

Comment: btw int.Parse will throw excception if the value is null so it does not handle null values. so better use int.TryParse